# PostgreSQL - Execution plan - Actual time meaning

Tags: postgresql

I have a question regarding the meaning of actual time in an execution plan.

I read the following things but they seem to be contradictory:

1. The first value is the time to retrieve the first line and the seconds value is the time to retrieve the last line.
2. When I want to know which operation takes a long time, I take the second value of actual time of the outer operation and the second value of actual time of the inner operation.

Example:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY c1;

QUERY PLAN
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­-> Sort(cost=172682.84..175182.84 rows=1000000 width=37)(actual time=612.793..729.135 rows=1000000 loops=1)
   Sort Key: c1
   Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 45952kB
   -> Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..18334.00 rows=1000000 width=37)(actual time=0.017..111.068 rows=1000000 loops=1)
Total runtime: 772.685 ms
```

According to the point 1, the sort operations takes (729 - 612) 117ms.

According to the point 2, the sort operation takes 618 ms.

Can anybody explain to me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption 1) is wrong.

The first time is the time it takes to *initialize* the step. The second time is the *total* time the step took (including child steps).

So the total time for the sort step is 729ms - 111ms of that were spent retrieving the data through a Seq Scan.